# Undesirable space in bash string concatenation

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

I can't figure out what is the problem with my following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function jsonValue() {
    key=$1
    num=$2
    awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'$key'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | sed -n ${num}p
}

json='{"_id": "dummy_id","title": "dummy_title"}'
id=$(echo $json | jsonValue _id)
title=$(echo $json | jsonValue title)

echo ${id}/${title}
```

The result is:

```
dummy_id title/ dummy_title
```

The function result does not contain space.
Have you any idea what is the problem with the function?

Comment: You didn't include a space in FS, so the field is `' "dummy_title"'` (with a leading space).

Comment: Seems like a job for `jq`.

Comment: You should copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about. See also [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Comment: What will you do when you have `json='{"_id": "1", "title": "this, is; a \"title\" {1}"}'`?

Answer (score 1):

> Have you any idea what is the problem with the function?

The problem is that your parser is very very poor and does not handle JSON strings with any spaces between `:` and beginning of the value. It also does not handle embedded `,` `;` `"` in the values.

Do not reinvent the wheel - JSON is a well known format. Use tools and libraries designed to handle JSON. Use `jq`, use Python or Perl.

Comment: You are right, normally I use jq for that, but I got an only bash env to solve a problem, so i am not able to install it. This function could be sufficient for only this job.

Comment: For 10000% you have perl, but also https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk

Comment: @KamilCuk : _"Use jq, use Python or Perl"_ **or Ruby** :-D